# Capistrano 3 - task being executed twice when in multiple roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

In my deploy.rb I have some custom tasks like this:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'setup environment'
  task :env do
    on roles(:web) do
      invoke 'symlink:env_file'
      invoke 'config:foreman'
    end
  end

  before  'assets:precompile', 'env'
end
```

My server definition looks like this:

```
server "my.app.ip", roles: %w{app web}, primary: true
server "my.resque.server.ip", roles: %w{resque web}
```

Essentially my 'app' server is responsible for running the main rails app, and my resque box runs the background jobs. But they both have the web role, because they both configure/run nginx + foreman through my own custom hooks.

When I run my cap deploy command I keep running into errors like this:

```
Skipping task `symlink:env_file'.
Capistrano tasks may only be invoked once. Since task `symlink:env_file' was previously invoked, invoke("symlink:env_file") at config/deploy.rb:133 will be skipped.
If you really meant to run this task again, first call Rake::Task["symlink:env_file"].reenable
```

I really just want those commands to run once per server. My expectation based on the roles definition within the task is that those tasks would get invoked once for each 'web' server in my server group. Why is it executing things multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capistrano is not designed to run arbitrary tasks within an `on` block. The only things that you should put inside an `on` block are SSH-execution commands such as:

- `test`
- `execute`
- `capture`
- `upload!`
- `download!`

You should never use `invoke` inside an `on` block.

In your case, the `on` block gets executed once *per :web server*, which means `invoke` is most certainly being called multiple times.

Instead, why not use the `before` declaration for both tasks?

```
before 'assets:precompile', 'deploy:symlink:env_file'
before 'assets:precompile', 'deploy:config:foreman'
```

Comment: Thank you, works well now and I have a better understanding of capistrano.  Is there a way to tell capistrano to run all commands in a namespace? For example if I have another task in my custom 'config' namespace I would have to add a new line to make it run.